# Why do my divs occupy 12-col even if I input 6-col?

Tags: bootstrap-4, grid, row

I am trying to split my 4 divs into two columns using col-5. But when it reaches a smaller screen size, all 4 divs occupy 12-col instead of 5-col each, resulting in a one complete column.

I'm new to coding and bootstrap! So sorry for the novice mistakes....

This is my code:

```
<section id="tools" class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="row  mt-5 text-center">
          <h1 class="col-12">Tools </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center ">
         <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" >
            <div class="col-5 col-lg-2 card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-3">
              <img src="./images/html.png" class="img-fluid" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-lg-2 card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-3">
              <img src="./images/html.png" class="img-fluid" >
            </div>
            <div class=" col-5 col-lg-2 card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-3">
              <img src="./images/html.png" class="img-fluid" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-lg-2 card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-3">
              <img src="./images/html.png" class="img-fluid" >
            </div>
         </div>

          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" >
            <div class="col-5 col-lg-2 card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-3">
              <img src="./images/html.png" class="img-fluid" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-lg-2 card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-3">
              <img src="./images/html.png" class="img-fluid" >
            </div>
            <div class=" col-5 col-lg-2 card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-3">
              <img src="./images/html.png" class="img-fluid" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-lg-2 card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-3">
              <img src="./images/html.png" class="img-fluid" >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the class `col-xs-6` for `divs` you want them to be half of the screen on small devices

`xs` means extra small devices , like mobile devices.

```
<div class="col-5 col-xs-6 col-lg-2 card d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-3">
```